# J2ME Midlet - Self-signed certificate

Tags: java, java-me, certificate, midp, midlet

I want to sign my application but I don't want its users to install certificates on their phones before installing my application. Is it possible to sign j2me midlet with self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, for this you need to purchase signing certificate from the verisign. I do have same sign certificate, which costs 20000 Rs ( one time ).

Comment: So there is no free way to self-sign midlets just like it's done in Android apps?

Comment: Sorry for this, but there is no free way of it. I also tried to search many websites for free one. but result was negative only.

Comment: you are welcome dear, I believe It is just sharing of knowledge.