# Annoying messages in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, signing

I came across this line from the Nokia dev site. It seems to suggest that there are two ways of getting rid of those annoying confirmation messages when accessing protected services in j2me. Does anybody have any clue as to what might be the other method apart form signing?

"This document describes how to code sign a Java ME app using Thawte. This is one of two mechanisms for avoiding security messages when accessing secured APIs."

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Thawte_signing_for_Java_ME

Answer (score 0):

Those Messages are because of your Application is not Signed with the required certificates.

Please look at to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164122/j2me-midlet-self-signed-certificate/8164404#8164404).

Not everyone can access the all API's of the Phone. To give a security to phone, Nokia has put those restrictions. Otherwise it may easy to create Mobile Virus too like computer virus.